# Return json from rest controller using object mapper manually

Tags: json, spring, objectmapper

I have a rest controller returning a json list of objects. When I call method 1) it works as required. 
When I need to configure serialisation to ignore certain properties in one request but not the other, I am using mixIn annotation and objectMapper. When I return the object it is in xml instead of json as before. Can anybody help? I realise I am now returning a string but if I want the same respose as 1) do I need to convert string to object and return in responseEntity as before.

1)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ResponseEntity<List<MyObject>> search(@RequestBody SearchParams searchParams){
  List<MyObject> result = myService.find(searchParams);
  return new ResponseEntity<List<MyObject>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

returns

```
[
  {"prop1":"val1", "prop2":"val2"},
  {"prop1":"val3", "prop2":"val4"}
]
```

2)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> search(@RequestBody SearchParams searchParams){  
  List<MyObject> result = myService.find(searchParams);
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(MyObject.class, MyObjectFilter.class);
  String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(result);
  return new ResponseEntity<String>(json, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

returns

```
<data contentType="text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1" contentLength="*"><![CDATA[
[
  {"prop1":"val1", "prop2":"val2"},
  {"prop1":"val3", "prop2":"val4"}
]
]]></data>
```

This appears in xml tab in soapui instead of json tab. Can anybdy help?

Comment: Have you tried to set content type manually? Like @RequestMapping(value = . . ., produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")